# How to convert a String AM/PM date to Timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, date, java-7

I want to parse a date that includes AM/PM format from String to Timestamp.

Although when I try to parse this date:
Dec 31 2017 12:00AM

I get a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Dec 31 2017 12:00AM"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at test.DatteTest.main(DatteTest.java:16)
```

My code:

```
String endDate = "Dec 31 2017 12:00AM";         
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(endDate);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
System.out.println(endDate);
System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Am I doing something wrong in the simpledateformat?
"MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa"?

Comment: for starts stop using `SimpleDateFormat`... and are you sure about the error? works just fine for me

Comment: My company's program is using java SE7.. not my choice.. @Eugene

Comment: Are you trying the second block of code?@Eugene

Comment: [here](https://ideone.com/KiZ40a)

Comment: May need to set the locale to English.

Comment: @Eugene this same code does not work for me. It throws an exception.

Comment: @TiiJ7 where should I set the locale?

Comment: new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: There's a [backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/) of the JSR-310 types for Java 7.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. this worked !! If you want post your answer so I can mark it as best answer

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to your project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input date contains a word in english. You have to give the locale :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy hh:mmaa", Locale.ENGLISH);
```